# display product attribute and taxonomy in woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, taxonomy

I want to display the Brand attribute from the Additional Info on the product page. Is there a way to create a shortcode because i have a specific location to display it or even in php.

This is for woocommerce 3.6.5

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to do the above -

```
// to display product additional info in product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_additional_info_product_summary', 45 );
// To diplay additonal info via shortcode within product page
add_shortcode( 'show_additional_info', 'show_additional_info_product_summary' );
function show_additional_info_product_summary() {
    global $product;
    // Assume that your attribute is pa_brand
    $brand_attributes = $product->get_attribute('brand');
    ?>
    <table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--brand">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo ucfirst( 'brand' ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo $brand_attributes; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
// to remove additional info tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_additional_info_tab', 99 );
function remove_additional_info_tab( $tab ) {
    if( isset( $tab['additional_information'] ) ) unset( $tab['additional_information'] );
    return $tab;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want to take the Brand attribute from it and display it on the product page, not the whole attributes set.

Comment: @markswta I updated my answer as per your needs. Please check.