# WooCommerce how to display specific "Additional Information" fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I am a total WooCommerce noob and I am struggling with something that I feel should be pretty simple...

How can I display specific "Additional Information" fields on a product page? I suppose I need to add some shortcode in the PHP files, but I am lost on what exactly to add...

I have ~15 additional info fields that I created under "Attributes" on the product.

I would like to display specific attributes on various parts of the page, but not all in one spot, much like the "Additional Fields" tab does.

I can't seem to find a straight answer and I am really struggling with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I realize there is a lack of information.

To further explain what I was trying to do, I was attempting to create a shortcode function in order to display specific "Attribute" fields from the woocommerce product.

[image: The attribute field in WooCommerce Product]

In order to do this, I found a solution. This code can be added to your theme's `function.php` file:

```php
// To diplay formula via shortcode within product page
add_shortcode( 'show_formula', 'show_additional_info_formula' );
function show_additional_info_formula() {
    global $product;
    $formula = $product->get_attribute('Formula');
    ?>
    <table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--formula">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo ucfirst( 'Formula' ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo $formula; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Then, the shortcode to use, is (in this instance), `[show_formula]`.

You can modify this to match your desired outcome.

Change:

```php
add_shortcode( 'show_your_info', 'show_additional_info_attribute_field' );

$your_field = $product->get_attribute('actual_woocommerce_field_name');

<tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--unique_name">

<th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo ucfirst( 'word_to_be_displayed' ); ?></th>

<td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo $your_field; ?></td>
```

Then, once modified, the `shortcode` you'd use:

`[show_your_field]`

[image: The field being displayed]

[This answer led me down the right path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087860/display-product-attribute-and-taxonomy-in-woocommerce-product-page)